# Fail to use ng-include inside WEB-INF directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a web project on tomcat apache 8. I am trying to include a jsp loacted in the WEB-INF directory. I fail to include it with angular.

directory *webapp* contains: `index2.jsp`

directory *webapp/WEB-INF* contains: `fragment1.html`

index2.jsp

```
<html>
...
<div ng-include src="'WEB-INF/view/fragment1.html'"></div> --  http://localhost:8080/Architect/WEB-INF/view/fragment1.html 404 (Not Found)

<%@ include file="WEB-INF/view/fragment1.html" %>    --  success
...
</html>
```

Why do I fail to include fragment1.html with angularJS?

Comment: Because angular doesn't know anything about java web apps. Put the view at the top level of your Web content, and refer it to it by only the web content path.

Comment: WEB-INF is the **only** directory inside a webapp that is inaccessible from the outside. So don't put views that must be accessible in WEB-INF. Put them anywhere else. WEB-INF is for you secret configuration, classes, libraries.

Comment: So why does <%@ include file="WEB-INF/view/fragment1.html" %>   is working well?    what is the diffrent with ng-include?